# How can I accept a buy offer for a specific NFT from a given collection on OpenSea using a Solidity smart contract?

Tags: nft, signature, opensea, seaport

How can I accept a buy offer for a specific NFT from a given collection on OpenSea using a Solidity smart contract?

I have an NFT collection X listed on OpenSea and there are several buy offers. I want to accept the highest buy offer for a specific Token ID (e.g. [1](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport/blob/b13939729001cb12f715d7b73422aafeca0bcd0d/contracts/lib/ConsiderationStructs.sol#L104)) that belongs to me using a Solidity smart contract.

One possible solution I have considered is to create a smart contract that utilizes the OpenSea Seaport library. The owner would transfer the NFT to this contract and then call the seaport.[fulfillBasicOrder_efficient_6GL6yc](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport/blob/b13939729001cb12f715d7b73422aafeca0bcd0d/contracts/interfaces/SeaportInterface.sol#L398)(parameters); function with the appropriate parameters.

The parameters argument is a [BasicOrderParameters](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/seaport/blob/b13939729001cb12f715d7b73422aafeca0bcd0d/contracts/lib/ConsiderationStructs.sol#L104) struct that contains various fields such as the consideration token, offer token, offer amount, start and end times, and additional recipients. However, I am unsure about the signature field and how to calculate it.

```
     * @param signature A signature from the offerer indicating that the order has been approved.
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to properly use the [Seaport](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/seaport-interface) to accept a buy offer for a specific NFT using Solidity. Additionally, I am open to any alternative solutions that achieve the same goal.

Comment: Did you solve it? I also encountered the same problem.